# failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c npm install" did not complete successfully: exit code: 132

Tags: docker-compose

**I'm trying to run docker and I'm getting `exit code: 132` error. What could it be?**

```
$ docker compose up
[+] Building 21.3s (9/11)
 => [frontend internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                              0.2s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 193B                                                                                                                                                       0.1s
 => [frontend internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                 0.2s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                                            0.0s
 => [frontend internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/node:13.12.0-alpine                                                                                                            3.3s
 => [frontend auth] library/node:pull token for registry-1.docker.io                                                                                                                       0.0s
 => [frontend 1/6] FROM docker.io/library/node:13.12.0-alpine@sha256:cc85e728fab3827ada20a181ba280cae1f8b625f256e2c86b9094d9bfe834766                                                      0.0s
 => [frontend internal] load build context                                                                                                                                                 4.4s
 => => transferring context: 1.21MB                                                                                                                                                        4.3s
 => CACHED [frontend 2/6] WORKDIR /app                                                                                                                                                     0.0s
 => CACHED [frontend 3/6] COPY package*.json ./                                                                                                                                            0.0s
 => ERROR [frontend 4/6] RUN npm install                                                                                                                                                  13.2s
------
 > [frontend 4/6] RUN npm install:
------
failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c npm install" did not complete successfully: exit code: 132
```

i tried to put nodejs

Comment: error code indicates npm binary is not right for your system.

Comment: I had to change the dockerfile

FROM node:14-alpine

, 

Now he looks like this

# build env
FROM node:14-alpine
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . ./
RUN npm run build
CMD cp -r build result_build